# InnoSetup: How do I Run a 64bit Installer while installing a 32 bit application, getting File not found

Tags: inno-setup, 32bit-64bit

I am using InnoSetup to install a 32 bit desktop application and in the Run section I am launching the 64bit Firebird installer. I am working in Win10.

But no matter what I have tried doing, I get an error message saying it cannot be run and that the file cannot be found, Error 2.

The FB3.0 installer file is visible in the Explorer and can launched via the explorer just fine. The 32 bit Firebird installer launches fine with my app's installation.

I have been using {tmp} directory and did try other directories, including C:\Temp. Nothing worked.

I have  PrivilegesRequired=admin and tried ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64 ia64. That did not work. I tried making sure that I manually select "run as admin" when launching the installer.

Flags include "Flags: runascurrentuser waituntilterminated postinstall 64bit" for the Firebird installer in Run section.

I tried using Exec() in the BeforeInstall of the launch of my app, but that gave the same error message.

In InnoSetup Help under, "64-bit Installation Limitations" It says:

"You cannot load/use 64-bit DLLs in the [Code] section, because Windows does not allow 32-bit processes to load 64-bit DLLs (and vice versa). A 32-bit process can, however, launch 64-bit EXEs. Use the Exec function or the [Run] section to do that."

Thus, I am still thinking I am missing something.

During a test run of an installer that just tried to launch FB3.0 installer, 64 bit, initially that would not run either with the same error, but once I explicitly added PrivilegesRequired=admin, that worked. Alternatively, in InnoScript, tools: options: general; check run as admin (which does not set the PrivilegesRequired=admin, btw, not sure where it is reflected in the script.)

Anyway, as soon as I included my app's installation (32bit), back came the error above.

Any ideas on how I can run the 64 bit installer in Inno with my 32 bit app installation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create an installer which loaded/ran a simple application and launch the Firebird 3.0 x64 installer without any errors.

From that I eventually discovered that the command line parameters for Firebird 3,0 were causing this issue, even though the params were taken right from the manual.

The parameter causing the error was:  /COMPONENTS="ServerComponent\SuperServerComponent,ServerComponent,DevAdminComponent,ClientComponent" following this is /TASKS="comma separated list of task names" which in my case includes /TASKS=""UseSuperServerTask\UseGuardianTask, et al...

I had to remove "ServerComponent\SuperServerComponent" from the parameter list. I am not sure that SuperServer is properly setup this way, but the Firebird 3.0 x64 installer does run properly from within my application installer now.

In any case, I use a separate firebird.conf file which is copied into the Firebird directory after firebird is installed and this sets the super server. Thank you for your response, Martin.

I suppose an additional flag for this post should include "Firebird" Not sure how to add flags after posting.